# Automatically returning to the application after dialing the number in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone re-dialer application in which a number is dialed and if the call is waiting then it will once again redial. But my application is exiting when number is dialed. I don't want that, it should automatically return.
Can somebody help me in solving the problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. You should save your application state when the call is received, so that the user can pick up where he or she left off in your application, after taking the call.

Comment: Is there any external or private framework available to achieve this functionality. I can also use Private framework. If its not achieved then there is no concept of re-dialing through my application.

Comment: You *might* be able to find a way to do this with [OS 4](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/iphone/whats-new.html#multitasking) but you'll have to ask on Apple's dev forums where OS 4 discussions are allowed (it's under NDA).

Answer (score 0):

Create a ‘UIWebView‘ that's hidden and use it load a ‘tel:‘ URL request. It will prompt you to make the call but when the call finishes you'll be returned to your app.

File a bug though to make it proper API though.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution which Ashley suggested works well.
I tried it and the control returns back to the app after call is disconnected.
Also using a webView one can use letter like 1-800-CallUS, etc for dialing.
Declare a webview, create a html file with phone# as a link(this link is automatically detected in your app) and import the file in resources and load the html in a string variable , add this subview to your main view.